# Pesquisa aleatório laravel

Tags: laravel

Estou efetuando uma consulta aleatório na tabela `users` da minha aplicação em `laravel`, exemplo abaixo:
`User::inRandomOrder()->paginate(10)`

Ele realmente me retorna o resultado de forma aleatório, mas preciso que todo o registro da tabela `users` com a coluna `users_destaque = 1` seja listado primeiro de forma aleatório, e todo registro com a coluna `users_destaque = 0` seja listado depois e também de forma aleatório, fico no aguardo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deves colocar também a tua ordenação princípal, neste caso ...`('users_destaque', 'DESC')`.

Tenta o seguinte, versões Laravel < 5.2:

```
User::orderBy('users_destaque', 'DESC')->orderByRaw("RAND()")->paginate(10);
```

Para uma versão de Laravel >= 5.2 é como estavas a fazer, com acrescento da ordenação principal:

```
User::orderBy('users_destaque', 'DESC')->inRandomOrder()->paginate(10);
```

Comment: estou ultilizando o laravel 5.4, tento esse código mesmo ?

Comment: Olá @BrunoSantos, nesse caso é o segundo exemplo que deves usar